# How to inspect only new Java code?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, inspect

I need to ensure that lines are no more than 80 characters long and that all variables are final (but this restriction only applies to *new* code).

Using IntelliJ inspection, is there a way to check only newly-created code?
By new, I mean that I've changed the code on a local Git repository, but I haven't pushed yet to remote repository.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @JFPicard the question has been edited - would you be willing to check again and judge if it is now on-topic? (I am unable to vote to re-open.) I edited it the way I did because the initial tags and an (accepted) answer led me to believe that OP already had a specific tool and was looking for information on how to use that tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run `Analyze` | `Inspect Code` with the **Changed Files** scope:

[image: scope]

Also vote for this feature request:

- [IDEA-154018](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-154018) Limit pre-commit inspections to modified region of code